# JAVA call Stored Procedure with a delete and insert statement

Tags: java, t-sql, stored-procedures, resultset

My SP do include a DELETE and a INSERT INTO statement. If DELETE statement success, but INSERT INTO do not, JAVA will only look at the first statement and concluded that the whole SP was executed successfully, which might be wrong.

How can I executed more then one statement and get a exception in JAVA if just one of the statement fails.
I have been tried with TRY-CATCH in SQL but it all concluded that the all statement was executed correctly because the first statement success.

It is a MS SQL 2008 Database

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [testing] 
    @bikes  varchar(8000), 
    @groupw varchar(4), 
    @name char(6)

AS
BEGIN


        DELETE CP_customer_kngr_corr_s WHERE knid in ('blue')

        DECLARE @pos INT
        DECLARE @len INT
        DECLARE @value varchar(8000)

        set @pos = 0
        set @len = 0
        set @bikes= @bikes  +','

        WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @bikes, @pos)>0 BEGIN
            set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @bikes, @pos+1) - @pos
            set @value = SUBSTRING(@bikes, @pos, @len)

            INSERT INTO [bikes]
               ([bikes])
            VALUES
                (@value)

            set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @bikes, @pos+@len) +1
        END 
END
```

Comment: What do you mean with _"JAVA will only look at the first statement and concluded that the whole SP was executed successfully"_? You are probably misinterpreting the results. Please show how you call the procedure from Java and how you conclude that only the first statement was executed. You probably need to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored procedure or you need to iterate over **all** results returned to the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rowcount for delete and raise error if number of rows deleted are zero and for insert statements you can use try/catch and raise error in catch block.

```
//Perform delete
select @@ROWCOUNT

if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  //RAISE ERROR

BEGIN TRY
 //perform insert here 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
       @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
       @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

-- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return 
-- error information about the original error that 
-- caused execution to jump to the CATCH block.
RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
           @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
           @ErrorState -- State.
           );

END CATCH;
```

Also check the error state returned by `ERROR_STATE` before passing it as a value to the state parameter of `RAISERROR`

Cheers !!

Comment: When I do as you suggest, it work as aspected if I call the SP on the SQL server. It return a table with "errror" or "success". But my JAVA says it do not return a resultset because it return by the first DELETE statement.

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

Comment: What is the underlying error messsage, was there any failure in delete or insert ??

Comment: Sachin Thapa, you solution are good for the DELETE statement, because this will most of the time be correct. My problem was also that SET NOCOUNT ON; was not set.

Answer (score 1):

What database is this? In most databases you can do a RAISEERROR when an operation fails. That would lead to an JDBCException been thrown.

You can check if the insert has succeeded by checking @@rowcount. If the number of rows effected is zero, you might want to throw an exception.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Comment: It is a MS SQL 2008 Database. I know the RAISEERRROR works in this vision. But how would you re-write the SP?

Comment: you might want to use @@rowcount to track if the insert succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my SP was that the     `SET NOCOUNT ON;` was not set. There by it return that the delete was a success and not a SELECT statement.

Here are the final result.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [testing] 
    @bikes  varchar(8000), 
    @groupw varchar(4), 
    @name char(6)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DELETE CP_customer_kngr_corr_s WHERE knid in ('blue')

        DECLARE @pos INT
        DECLARE @len INT
        DECLARE @value varchar(8000)

        set @pos = 0
        set @len = 0
        set @bikes= @bikes  +','

        WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @bikes, @pos)>0 BEGIN
            set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @bikes, @pos+1) - @pos
            set @value = SUBSTRING(@bikes, @pos, @len)

            INSERT INTO [bikes]
               ([bikes])
            VALUES
                (@value)

            set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @bikes, @pos+@len) +1
        END 
END
```